# Entity / Code First / SQL Database - Same parameter but differents values

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sdf

**Context**

I'm a beginner in Entity / CodeFirst and SQL database.

I would to build a table with the same parameter:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 | F7 |
-----------------------------------------
|  1 |1000| 500| 250| 100| 50 |    |    |
|  2 | 500| 250| 125|    |    |    |    |
|  3 | 250| 125| 100|    |    |    |    |
|  4 | 200| 100|    |    |    |    |    |
|  5 | 100| 50 |    |    |    |    |    |
-----------------------------------------
```

Fs1 to 7 is a list the same parameter with different value.

**Questions**

- What's the correct way to describe it in taking into Code First consideration?

I suppose this way isn't correct...

```
    public class FsTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double F1 { get; set; }
        public double F2 { get; set; }
        public double F3 { get; set; }
        public double F4 { get; set; }
        public double F5 { get; set; }
        public double F6 { get; set; }
        public double F7 { get; set; }

    }
```

- What's the correct way to fill this table with values above?

Comment: You could connect to your database with SQL Server Management Studio and add rows there, or add the values via code. Have you created the DB yet? [Check out this great article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) about EF code first to a new DB.

Comment: My problem is a design problem not a building problem. I would to know what's is the correct way to design a table with an "array" of the same param but with different enum.

Comment: The 8 column table you posted above is the best way to accomplish what you want if you're sure that you'll never need more than 7 entries per ID. If you're not sure, make 2 new tables called `Item` and `TableItem`. `TableItem` will have an ID for `FsTable` and `Item`, allowing you to store many `Item`'s per `FsTable`. If you need an example, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all think about colums without value. Should they be nullable or not? You can seed your Db from the Seed method.

If you are using console aplication you need to invoke some operation over the database so you can create it

Ps. Check out Repository Pattern

Comment: My problem is a design problem not a building problem. 

I would to know what's is the correct way to design a table with an "array" of the same param but with different enum.

Comment: Do you think a Collection could be better ?

Comment: You can use whatever you want once you retrieve the data, but you can't store it as a `collection` or an `array` in your DB. Your columns will be of `int` type (judging by your code above), and you can store them in whatever you want in your C# code. Make the columns nullable so that when you iterate thru your `array` or `collection`, no errors will be thrown if the length is less than 6 (again, going by your F1-F7 code above). I think you're making this harder than it actually is.